# Windows task scheduler edit multiple tasks together

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks

Windows 2008 server.

Is it possible to edit multiple tasks at the same time (batch update)?

I have several tasks. I want to edit the command line in the action tab. The tasks are automatically created by a build process and are executed later (single run). The task also removes itself, so there are no leftovers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I did to resolve my needs:

- List all tasks to a csv file: **schtasks /query /v /fo csv > c:\temp\tasks.csv**
- Using regex, I edited the csv file to leave only the task name and action
- Edit the csv file with the updates I want (my case - the action)
- Batch file with a loop to go over all entries in the file and run **schtasks /change /tn "name" /tr "new action" /rp**

A sample line in the csv: **"my task name","my new action"**

The batch file content:

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%a in (C:\temp\tasks.csv) do (
    echo Fixing Task: %%a
    schtasks /change /tn %%a /tr %%b /rp <password>
)
```

I hope this helps...